# React mask input with only last 4 digits visibles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dom

I'm trying to create a custom input to mask SSN value but I want to hide first values and only show last 4 digits.

Expected behavior:

[image]

What I get when I use [react-input-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask):

[image]

My code:

```
<InputMask maskPlaceholder={null} mask="9999-99-9999" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
```

Comment: Can you show us what `InputMask`'s code looks like?  Also, if you are sending the full value to the client and then just obfuscating the first digits client side, that's not secure at all.

Comment: That component comes from this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask. I'm working in a registration form, so it should be work as a partial password field.

Answer (score -5):

```
function masking(data){
let output=data.toString().subString(7,10);

output="XXXXXXX"+output;
return output
}
masking(1234567890);
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.